# Adding tuples to lists in nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, data-manipulation

I would like to add a tuple to a list for data that I already have in a nested dictionary format if it is missing.

```
all_cap = {"cap_1":{"id":1001, "vitals":[("Temp", 101), ("HR", 60)]}, "cap_2": 
{"id":1002, "vitals":[("Temp", 104), ("HR", 60), ("RR", 12)]}}
```

So, if I went to add a tuple ("RR", 16) to cap_1 it would work, but if I wanted to add it to cap_2 it would not overwrite the RR that is already there or even add the second RR to it.  I've tried going in to it like this:

```
def add_vital(dict, str, int):
  if all_cap[dict]["vitals"][0][0:len("vitals")] == str:
    return True
  else:
    all_caps[dict]["vitals"].append(str, int)
    return False
```

I know that I have been asking quite a few questions on here today, and I truly do appreciate the answers I have received.  It has been helping, but I just started trying to do some work in Python today (before now, I have only used R), so getting up and running with some of it has been daunting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with lists of tuples by searching over them, but based on usage it really seems like these should just be dicts of dicts.

```
all_cap = { 
    "cap_1": { "id": 1001, "vitals": {
        "Temp": 101, 
        "HR": 60,
    }},
    "cap_2": { "id": 1002, "vitals": {
        "Temp": 104,
        "HR": 60,
        "RR": 12,
    }},
}
```

Now your `add_vital` function is just:

```
def add_vital(cap_id, vital, value):
    # type: (str, str, int) -> bool
    if vital in all_cap[cap_id]["vitals"]:
        return True
    else:
        all_cap[cap_id]["vitals"][vital] = value
        return False
```

Given the structure you've got, I think you need something more like:

```
def add_vital(cap_id, vital, value):
    # type: (str, str, int) -> bool
    if any([vital_pair[0] == vital 
            for vital_pair in all_cap[cap_id]["vitals"]]):
        return True
    else:
        all_cap[cap_id]["vitals"].append((vital, value))
        return False
```

Comment: I like that option for in the future, unfortunately I currently have a lot more dictionaries like the one with the tuples in it, so I can't change the whole structure of the dictionaries, I need to be able to go through and check them out while keeping them in the same structure they are already in.

Comment: Updated with a way to do it via list comprehension and the `any` function.

Comment: I tried running this, but as it is, it will not work for me.  The vital_pair part seems to be the problem.  Written like that, it is an object that is not defined, but switched to vital.pair, it is an object without a pair attribute (at leas these are the two errors I am getting).

Comment: Ah, the list comprehension needs to be `for vital_pair in all_cap...`